# How to replace cursor with crosshair in Highcharts React?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2eje4xxb/1/) example, the cursor is a crosshair when hovering over the entire chart area. I am using Highcharts React however and the above example uses jQuery.

I cannot get this to work with Highcharts React - I have found the documentation for `plotOption.series.cursor` [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.cursor), but this only allows me to show a crosshair pointer when hovering over a data point, not the whole chart area.

How can I make this work in Highcharts React?

Answer (score 1):

There was an extremely easy solution which was extremely hard to find which is:

```js
chart: {
  style: {
    cursor: 'crosshair',
  },
}
```

Search in the Highcharts docs and you will not find this.